# Java Swing making the thread wait once

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I'm trying to make my GUI wait for 2 seconds after a recent update in the graphics. It means that after I use:

```
    boardLogo.repaint();
    boardLogo.revalidate();
```

I want the GUI to wait before making further computations and then paint them again.

The code:

```
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingWorker swingWorkerExample = new SwingWorker(){
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        return null;
                    }
                    protected void done(){
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(2000); //wait 2 seconds.
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                swingWorkerExample.execute();
            }
        });
        //.... more code here
        boardLogo.repaint();
        boardLogo.revalidate();
```

But when I run it - first it executes the last two lines, then waits for 2 seconds...

To be honest, my knowledge about Threads and Java Swing is not the best (especially when it comes to understanding swing worker, which I've tried to read about from Oracle site), so I would appreciate it if the answer will be detailed.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a javax.swing.Timer.

Comment: [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm in a function and don't have the ActionListener that needed for the Timer Constructor... What can I do except sending the Listener itself to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I run it - first it executes the last two lines, then waits for 2 seconds ... my knowledge about Threads and Java Swing is not the best.

You say, *it* executes the last two lines.  Ever stop to wonder what *it* is?

*It* is a thread.  Threads are what execute code in a Java program, and every line that gets executed is executed by some thread.

When your code calls `invokeLater()`, it is submitting a *task* (i.e., a piece of code) to be executed by Swing's *event dispatch thread* (EDT); and when your code calls `swingWorker.execute()` it is submitting a task to be performed by one of Swing's *background threads*.

The whole point of having more than one thread in a program is that they can be doing different things *at the same time*.

In your case, you've got the EDT sleeping for two seconds while, at the same time, some other thread is calling `boardLogo.repaint();` and `boardLogo.revalidate();`

---

There's a couple of important things to know about Swing and multi-threading:

- All of your event handlers will be run by the EDT.
- An event handler should never do anything that takes more than a small fraction of a second, because your application will not be able to respond to any other events (i.e., it will appear to be "hung") until the handler returns.
- No *other* thread is allowed to interact with any of Swing's GUI components.

One important use-case for `invokeLater()` is, it's how code running in the background thread can communicate with GUI components.  invokeLater() submits a *task* (i.e., a piece of code) that will be run in the EDT.

The main use-case for SwingWorker is pretty much the opposite of that:  It's how an event handler, running in the EDT, can kick off a *task* that is going to take more than a small fraction of a second to complete.

---

You can learn about this stuff by working your way through the Swing Concurrency tutorial:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: Thanks! I've read your comment and the tutorial in the link above, but I still didn't fully get it. If I understand it correctly, in order to wait 2 seconds without freezing the GUI, I need to do it in the SwingWorker, because its purpose is for long tasks. But I still can't make it work so it will wait 2 seconds before updating the GUI again... Tried to use the get() method as listed in the tutorial, but I get the same result: the GUI freezes for 2 seconds BEFORE updating in the first time, and after 2 seconds updating the GUI for both times...

Comment: @orohev What does "make my GUI wait" mean?  If you want to draw something two seconds after some event, E, the normal way to do that is set up a `javax.swing.Timer` that will do the drawing after two seconds elapse.  If you want to prevent the user from operating some control for two seconds, the normal way to do that is to disable the control, and then use a `Timer` to re-enable it two seconds later.  You should be using swing timers for pretty much anything you want your swing application to do in real-time.

Comment: during the time I want to use the timer, the GUI should wait until the time is out, before calculating and presenting the result. I've tried using Timer as well, but it seems I really don't know how...

Comment: @orohev, Sorry, but I don't understand what "the GUI should wait" means.  According to the only design rules that I know, a GUI should never wait.  A Swing program responds to _events_; key presses, mouse clicks, ..., and _timer events_.  Any event handler that you write should always return within a few milliseconds of being called.  If "wait for 2 seconds" is not something you can accomplish by scheduling a timer event for two seconds in the future, then I don't know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. Lets say I want to do the calculations, and only then update the GUI. In the meanwhile, the GUI doesn't freeze, but performs normally (as you've suggested, I'll disable the control of the objects I need to "freeze").